# How can I implement a qsort with a dynamic data on a Kruskal function for graphs

Tags: c, algorithm, graph, kruskals-algorithm

I created a Kruskal funcion so it can find the smallest path on a graph. But I did it with a bubble sort and I'm trying to make it work using a qsort and making my structs dynamic so it can me more efficient.

All the functions used are working but if you have a doubt about it ask me so I can post it. I'm using union find as `pd(dynamcc partition)` to link.

My code is:

```
struct _temp{
    float weight;
    int source;
    int destination;
};
typedef struct _temp Temp;

struct _graph{

    int NumberVertex;
    int NumberEdges;
    float* NeighborMatrix;
};
typedef struct _graph Graph;


struct din_part{
    int n;
    int*v;
};
typedef struct din_part PartDin;


Graph* grKruskal(Graph* g) 
{
    Graph*   tree_min = graph_Create(g->NumberVertex);
    PartDin* p = pd_Create(g->NumberVertex);
    int i, j,number_edges=0,n=0,representative;
    Temp edges[300],temp;

    for (i = 0; i < (g->NumberVertex); i++)
    {
        for (j = n; j < (g->NumberVertex); j++)
        {
            if(g->NeighborMatrix[g->NumberVertex * i + j]!=0)
            {
                edges[number_edges].weight=g->NeighborMatrix[g->NumberVertex * i + j];
                edges[number_edges].source=i;
                edges[number_edges].destination=j;
                number_edges++;
            }
        }
        n++;
    }

    if(number_edges>0){
        for(i=0; i<number_edges; i++)
        {
            int change=0;
            for(j=0 ;j<number_edges-1; j++)
            {
                if(edges[j].weight >edges[j+1].weight){        // blubble_sort
                    temp=edges[j];
                    edges[j]= edges[j+1];
                    edges[j+1]=temp;
                    change=1;

                }
            }
            if(!change)
            {
                for(i=0;i<number_edges;i++)
                {
                    if(pd_Representative(p,edges[i].source)!=pd_Representative(p,edges[i].destination))
                    {
                        representative=pd_Union(p,edges[i].source,edges[i].destination);
                        graph_InsertEdge(arvore_min,edges[i].source,edges[i].destination,edges[i].weight);
                    }
                }
                p=pd_Free (p);
                return tree_min;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it mean to make your structs dynamic?

Comment: You could start by making your code more modular (i.e., by using functions). Putting everything into a single function is definitely not the easiest way to go. For instance, create a new function responsible for the sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use quicksort in C easily with the `qsort` function available in `<stdlib.h>`. You don't need your data structure to be dynamic, although it will help your program be more flexible.

Its signature is the following

```
void qsort ( void * base, size_t num, size_t size, int ( * comparator ) ( const void *, const void * ) );
```

`base` is the vector you want to sort.

`num` is the number of elements in your vector.

`size` is the size of each element, the one returned from `sizeof`.

`comparator` is a function pointer to a function that receives two `void` pointers and returns an `int`. This function must return positive if the first argument is larger than the second, negative otherwise, and 0 if they are equal.

In your case, you could simply replace the bubble sort part with

```
 qsort((void*)edges, number_edges, sizeof edges[0], comparator);
```

And define `comparator` as

```
 int edge_comparator(void *ptr1, void *ptr2){
     Temp edge1 = *((Temp *)ptr1);
     Temp edge2 = *((Temp *)ptr2);
     return edge1.weight - edge2.weight;
 }
```